# HP Pavilion: Sound problem after Windows Vista SP2 update

Tags: windows-vista, audio, sp2, hp-pavilion

I have HP Pavilion dv-2051et notebook with Windows Vista Home Premium SP1. Recently the sound of my notebook completely went off and I poked up Windows sound settings and IDT HD Sound panel to bring it back, but to no avail (trust me, I looked at every setting). Then I made a system restore to the point located just before Vista SP2 was installed. The sounds came back. Afterwards, I installed Vista SP2 again, and the sounds went off again. SP2 installation causes complete loss of sounds of my notebook. What can I do to overcome this problem? I don't want to stay with SP1 but installing SP2 brings me a huge problem. Anyone experienced this lately? Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [solution](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/psg/board/message?board.id=Sound&message.id=4204) (IDT - no sound after installing Vista SP2) suggests to uninstall the sound driver, restart the computer, windows will automatically install the drivers again, solved.

Comment: Thanks Molly, I've downloaded the newest sound driver from hp.com and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble on a toshiba laptop, it turned out to be a simple fix. The default audio playback device was not properly set (or had been reset). Check ControlPanel, Hardware and Sound, Manage Audio Devices, make sure the default output device is correct.